# Disable language extensions, #ifndef fails

Tags: visual-c++, pragma, precompiled-headers

This question refers to Visual Studio C++ 2010. If I disable language extensions, even the simplest toy program gets an error of "unexpected end-of-file found" when I include even an empty .h file. It appears that the problem lies with the #ifndef HEADER_THING trick for not including a header twice. If I omit that, the error message goes away.

Comment: The Visual Studio 2010 C++ compiler isn't a C++11 compiler, it's sort of a halfway house between C++03 and C++11. On this issue, disabling language extensions causes it to respect the C++03 standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it by googling. It is a bug in VC++ 2010. The workaround is to add a newline after every #endif at the end of header files.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/728179/unexpected-unexpected-end-of-file-found-found